# how to pull selected radio button in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, radio-button, radio-group

I have two radio buttons, and depending on which one is selected I want to send them to a specific jsp page. I do not know how to pull which button is selected in my java class.

Here is the jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="ttp.actions.Sale1Action.action">

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="packages"checked> packages<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="productions"> productions<br>

    <input type="submit" value="  next  "/>

</form>
```

here is the java:

```
public class Sale2Action implements Action {

    public String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        String prodPack = request.getParameter("radio1");
        System.out.println("radio1 = " + prodPack);
        String venueID = request.getParameter("venueid");
        Venue v = VenueDAO.getInstance().read(venueID);


        if (prodPack.equals("packages")) {
            return "sale3a.jsp";
        } else {
            return "sale3b.jsp";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a custom framework our professor gave us

Comment: It is a custom framework, so it is hard to help. Suggestion: consider your configuration file (e.g. web.xml), and your action attribute in the form tag. Good Luck:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the servlet, to determine which button is selected

```
String value = request.getParameter("radio1");
```

You will get the value. If you check packages, the value will be "packages". Radio group return one checked value.

Comment: Don't I already have that?? ``String prodPack = request.getParameter("radio1");``

Comment: So, then aren't you getting the right value in prodPack? If not, what is the value when you print the variable?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Do you consider your question as being answered? If yes, please consider marking the solution as accepted.